# Are colloborators not meant to see each others' custom reports?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have been invited to collaborate on creating custom reports in Google Analytics for a property (the admin/site owner has invited me to the account where the property is). I can access all the metrics and data collected for the property, but when I create custom reports, these are not visible to the admin (who is using a different email address to log in to manage the property).

1. Is this expected behaviour?
2. Can I do something to make my custom reports available to the admin, short of actually using his login credentials to create the reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [actively share reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en#AccessManageShare). They're saved and available only on a per-user basis.